# nginx location conflict for 2 ember-cli apps under one domain

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup 2 ember-cli apps under one domain on nginx.

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/bar
```

App 1 is stored under /var/www/foo, and App 2 is stored under /var/www/bar.

First prize is having the main root point to /var/www/bar, and having it set up so that the `/` points to foo and `/` points to bar. This is mostly for consistency in the way things are setup. However I'm happy to alter the setup just to get it to work.

I have the following nginx snippet:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/bar;

    location /bar {
        root /;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/foo;
        try_files $uri /index.html?/$request_uri;
    }
}
```

I have tried it the other way around, but also couldn't get it to work. It seems that `location /` overrides the location `/bar/`. If I comment out the `location /` directive, then `/bar` works, but obviously not `/`. Vice versa also works. How do I get both of these to work together?

*Note*: ember-cli isn't really a contributing factor at this point. Just getting index.html files to work will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter in the `try_files` directive is either a fallback code, location or URI. For the last two cases nginx make an internal redirect so the expected behaviour is to go to location `/`. You also make a mistake in `root` directive of location bar, `/` will match the root of your filesystem !

You need to change the fallback URI to `/bar/index.html?/$request_uri`. If understand well, you want to serve bar's index.html from `/var/www/bar/index.html`. Two solutions :

**[1]**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www;

    location /bar {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /bar/index.html?/$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/foo;
        try_files $uri /index.html?/$request_uri;
    }
}
```

**[2]**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/bar;

    location /bar/ {
        alias /var/www/bar/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /bar/index.html?/$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/foo;
        try_files $uri /index.html?/$request_uri;
    }
}
```